# Should there be a comma before “so” in the following sentence?

Tags: commas, conjunctions, dependent-clause, independent-clauses, coordinating-conjunctions

Consider the following sentence.

> JS-- is an optimizing compiler for the good parts of JavaScript, which helps programmers write efficient and type-safe code so they can develop better quality software and be more productive.

This sentence seems all right to me. However, when fed it to https://languagetool.org/, an online grammar checker, it complained about a missing comma before “so”. Did the online grammar checker make a mistake?

Comment: Yes; the comma is unnecessary. Mind you, I'd like the occasional pause when reading something this long too. // I'd change 'which' to 'It' (which also disambiguates to some extent).

Comment: The grammar is exactly the same no matter where you put commas, how you capitalize it, or even in most cases how you spell it. That's because no matter what you do in that arena, it's the same words in the same order.  Therefore the grammar is the same. What you're calling a grammar checker is just a writing checker.

Comment: @tchrist So, punctuation is not a part of grammar? Good to know.

Comment: Right: grammar is how to arrange pieces smaller than a word together into a word (morphology) and how to fit words themselves together into phrases, clauses, and sentences (syntax).  That's quite different from how you choose to write something down. A blind illiterate can and does speak and listen to grammatical sentences all day long, no writing involved. Language is speech, and it predates writing technologies.  Speech is primary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your hunch is right: the online grammar checker is wrong. You don't need a comma here. It's helpful to remember *so* can mean *and so* or *so that*. When it means *and so* and joins two independent clauses, a comma is generally considered necessary. For example, *Programmers can write efficient and type-safe code, [and] so good ones are in high demand*. But in your sentence, *so* means *so that* -- which does not need a comma. Grammar checkers often make this error, in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the accepted answer, but…

…there is still a problem with your sentence caused by a comma — the one following ‘Javascript’. Your sentence is better written without that comma and (arguably) with ‘which’ replaced by ‘that’:

> *JSwibble* is an optimizing compiler for the good parts of JavaScript **that**
>   helps programmers write efficient and type-safe code so they can
>   develop better-quality software and be more productive.

However, in both this and the original, the sentence is ambiguous or difficult to read because the relative pronoun follows ‘JavaScript’ rather than ‘compiler’. It is the *compiler* that helps programmers, not *JavaScript* (or its good parts). As often in technical writing, the solution to problems of ambiguity in long sentences is to split them in two:

> *JSwibble* is an optimizing compiler for the good parts of JavaScript.
>
> **It** helps programmers write efficient and type-safe code so they can
>   develop better-quality software and be more productive.

(I have also hyphenated the compound adjective, *better-quality*, to avoid false scent.)

**Why is the first comma wrong in the original sentence?**

This is a case of the distinction between what are called *defining and non-defining relative clauses.* The following explanation and rules are drawn from Fowler’s *The King’s English* (Third edition, 1931).

**A non-defining clause** is one that provides additional information but can be omitted without causing the sentence to lose its meaning. This is always introduced by a comma followed by ‘which’, e.g.

> *Xcode*, **which** can be downloaded from the Apple App Store, is widely used by iPhone coders.

If you remove the non-defining relative clause the sentence “Xcode is widely used…” still makes sense.

**A defining clause** is usually introduced by the relative pronoun, ‘that’, and in any case without a comma. It cannot be removed without the sentence losing meaning, e.g.

> The IDE **that** is most used by Java programmers is probably *Eclipse*.

The sentence “The IDE is probably *Eclipse*” conveys little or no meaning.

Admittedly the situation is a little more complicated in the example as an idea is presented before the relative pronoun — that *JSwibble* is a compiler and that it is used with a subset of Javascript — but the defining part of the sentence is clearly what *JSwibble* helps do.

**Footnote on *that* and *which* in defining clauses**

*Fowler* is very definitely against *which* in defining clauses, and *Microsoft’s* awful grammar checker rejoices in the simplification that this rule provides. However my impression is that it has now become a matter personal preference. Either that or I am trying to justify my own laxity in this respect.

Comment: Edwin Ashworth also mentioned that two sentences would be better than one, and I agree. Also, thanks for catching the missing hyphen in the compound adjective, better-quality. Your explanation was very insightful.